# Moving Magento 1.9 from one server to another

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9

We are trying to replicate Magento on a test server, but inspite of following the steps the site redirects to old url

1. Copied and installed Database and files on the new server
2. Fixed connections on the local.xml file
3. Reset the usecured and secured base url from the core_config_data
4. Cleared all files in var/cache var/session and var/tmp

There is no .htaccess file, and the index.php does not do any redirect.

What could we have missed?

Comment: Sounds good. Restart your browser, they cache 301/302 responses.

Comment: I've tried with other browsers, it doesn't seem to work. @Marius We are duplicating but the issues we are facing seem to be specific to latest magento version.

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: @brentwpeterson, tried that. It made no changes as such.

Comment: And you don't have compiling on I am assuming

Comment: yes, the compiling is off.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. If you used ssl on the live server, make sure the new stage urls aren't still using https and that ssl usage in core_config_data is switched off. "UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 where path = 'web/secure/use_in_frontend' or path = 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml)'".
2. Besides clearing the magento cache in the file system, switch the cache off as well through "UPDATE core_cache_option SET value=0".
3. Make sure your local.xml is configured to go directly against the DB and not some cache (like memcached). And double check it is the right DB :)
4. Make sure ALL your unsecured and secured base urls are changed. Remember you will have several if you have several store fronts. "UPDATE core_config_data SET value = REPLACE(value, 'www','stage') where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' or path = 'web/secure/base_url'"